# UITableView control what happens when highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to control what happens in my `UITableViewCell` when it is highlighted.

I know it is possible in iOS 6.0 like so:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But how I do it if I am targeting 5.0 and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom UITableViewCell you can override the

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method which will be called when the touch is down on the cell (the `highlighted`param will be YES) and when the touch is up or canceled(the `highlight` parameter is NO).

Also this approach will work on iOS 3.0 and later.

Comment: That is actually correct, god I am stupid I didn't think about this. I will try this out.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option on iOS 5 would be to use this method

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Though this method is called only when the user taps and then lifts their finger off the cell (as [explained here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)), but I am not aware of any other methods available in both 5.x and 6.x which you could use for this.

Comment: Yeah I tried that already, but unfortunately I need it while the finger is on top of the cell. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my project I was in the need to highlight my image immediately user touch the cell so i have implemented highlight state in  Ios 5.0 like this. These functions are written in custom cell class. Modify these functions according to your requirement.

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [self hightlightImage];
        [self performSelector:@selector(detecetedLongTap) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    -(void)detecetedLongTap{
        [self hightlightImage];
    }
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    { 

        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (titleLabel.textColor == [UIColor blackColor]) 
            [self hightlightImage];
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be the last resort if nothing else is better.